# Restore EFI from Windows after Windows 10 upgade broke boot list?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I updated to Windows 10 late July, and it deleted all of the boot entries on my computer. I was able to find the correct Windows boot efi file, and added the option to boot, but I could not find the ubuntu efi file. I can access files through windows, but I want to get back to using Ubuntu. What boot entry should I look for? If it isn't there, could I download the EFI file and add it to the correct place?

Comment: I had the same issue. I used this trick http://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
 This should show if it is efi boot files or some other issue.

Comment: @oldfred I would prefer not to have to flash boot repair, is there another way?

Comment: @abhishek Thanks sooo much! That worked. If you put an answer with an explination of _why_ it worked, I will accept it.

Comment: @IronManMark20 BTW, your question wasn't really Ubuntu-specific, it would have fit into [unix.se] as well.

Comment: @phk, good point. I didn't know that existed. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

***Assuming*** that your Ubuntu installation is intact (not a safe assumption), you should be able to get up and running again as follows:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a medium from the downloaded files.
3. If necessary, disable Secure Boot. (There are ways to do this with Secure Boot active, but they require adding more steps.)
4. Boot to the rEFInd medium. It should present you with options to boot both Windows and Ubuntu.
5. Highlight an Ubuntu option and hit the Enter key to launch it. (Caveat: If you have a separate `/boot` partition, you'll have to hit F2 or Insert twice, rather than Enter. This will open up a text editor in which you must add a `root={something}` option, where `{something}` is your root [`/`] filesystem, such as `/dev/mapper/ubuntu` or `/dev/sda6`.)
6. Once Ubuntu appears, you can either:

   - Re-install GRUB, probably by typing `sudo grub-install` at a command prompt.
   - Install rEFInd to the hard disk by installing the Debian package or PPA, as described in the rEFInd documentation.
7. If you disabled Secure Boot, you should be able to re-enable it at this point, although you might need to jump through some extra hoops if you replace GRUB with rEFInd, as described in the [rEFInd Secure Boot documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html)

If you go through this process and install GRUB at the very end, the result should be very similar to using Boot Repair; it's just that the steps to get there are different. Either way, if Windows has deleted your `grubx64.efi` file (and related files on the ESP), then those file(s) must be restored.

Getting back to the first word of this answer, though, checking the current state of the Ubuntu installation may be in order. To be sure, the procedure I've just outlined will fail miserably at step #4 if Ubuntu is missing -- rEFInd will show no Ubuntu entries (or possibly a GRUB entry that will ultimately fail). Furthermore, it's possible that everything remains installed, but your boot order has simply changed. You might think that GRUB has been deleted if you're looking on the wrong partition. Ubuntu sometimes installs GRUB to one partition even though Windows uses another one for its boot loader, so such confusion can occur pretty easily. In this scenario, it would be more efficient (but not necessarily more effective) to use `efibootmgr` in Linux to adjust the boot order. For all of these reasons, running the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and pasting a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates (posted on a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)) may be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it would work, but I was able to fix it without going through all these steps.

Comment: I overlooked this answer initially as it seemed "complicated" and had 0 votes. It is in fact a usefully detailed description of a fairly fool proof solution to problems recovering a boot loader. Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem like you and I solved it using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) which apparently is free for home use (on non-enterprise Windows editions). After installing and opening it just do the following:

1. Take the left choice *"Manage EFI Boot Option"*,
2. Click the button with the tooltip *"Create New Entry"* (center button row, 2<sup>nd</sup> from top).
3. Now enter or enter the file path of Shim: *"\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"* (or if Secure Boot is not active then you can alternatively also have it point to Grub directly), add a description like *"Ubuntu"* or similar and confirm by clicking OK.
4. Move the just created entry to the top (top button again in the center row).

That's it, it should automatically boot you into Grub again. No booting from flash drive or similar needed.

**Alternatively, if the Grub/Shim entry is still there, just not the first one in the boot order**

1. In an elevated prompt do:

   ```
   bcdedit /enum all
   ```
2. In its output look for the ID of your boot loader entry. It's similar to:

   ```
   Firmware Application (101fffff)
   -------------------------------
   identifier              {8b455a95-4c31-11e6-9f4c-8066cf6e9636}
   device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
   path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
   description             Ubuntu
   ```
3. Set it to be first which the attempts to boot:

   ```
   bcdedit /bootsequence <ID OF YOUR BOOT LOADER ENTRY>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it saved me a ton of trouble! One more tip for EasyUEFI: If you've got more than one hard drive you may have more than one EFI partition. If you click "Browse" for the entry path you can make sure the correct partition and file is selected for the boot entry.